# DropZone Bootstrap theme error adding multiple files in the list using Firefox for mobile

Tags: firefox, bootstrap-4, dropzone.js

i followed [this](https://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html) official example to use DropZone with Bootstrap theme, it works good in Chrome but i noticed a problem in Firefox for mobile, seems that it can't manage the multiple file addition, you can see it directly from the official example page, if you try to select more than 1 file per time (2 pics for example) the creation of the list fails, there is only one preview row with no preview image and 0 byte dimension text.

Here the example adding two pics in a single time:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just updated Firefox for Android at 79.0.5 version(08/17/20) and the problem is gone, but is still present in the previous versions, it would be very useful to understand what it is related to.